# Animation using AniMate with Unity3D doesn't interact with physical objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm designing a maze with Unity3D. The maze has a number of bifurcations and the player will stop before each bifurcation and simply choose left or right. Then an automatic animation will move the player through the next bifurcation till the end of the maze (or till a dead end).

To animate the player I'm using [AniMate](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/AniMate) and C# in my Unity project. Using AniMate I'm simply creating a point-to-point animation for each bifurcation (e.g. mage below: from the start/red arrow to point 5)[image: maze and animation with AniMate in Unity]

My problem is that my animation script (associated to the "First Person Controller") is not working properly since physics is not respected (the player passes through walls). If in the same project I enable the standard character controls in Unity, then I can navigate in the maze with the physical contrains of walls etc... (i.e. I have colliders).

This is an example of the code I'm using when I press left to pass from starting point, trough point 1 to point 2:

```
        void FixedUpdate () {
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
//To point 1
    Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
    props.Add("position", new Vector3(756f,112f,1124f));
    props.Add("physics", true);
    Ani.Mate.To(transform, 2, props);

//To point 2            
    Hashtable props2 = new Hashtable();
    props2.Add("position", new Vector3(731f,112f,1124f));
    props2.Add("physics", true);
    Ani.Mate.To(transform, 2, props2);
}
}
```

What happens practically when I press the left arrow button is that the player moves directly to point 2 using a straight line passing through the wall. I tried to pass to AniMate "Physics = true" but it doesn't seem to help.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Alternatively... any hint on how to have a more optimized code and just use a series of vector3 coordinates (one for each point) to obtain the simple animation I want without having to declare new Hashtable(); etc... every time?
I chose AniMate simply because 1. I'm a beginner with Unity 2. I don't need complex animations (e.g. I don't need to use iTween), just fixed animations along straight lines and I need something really simple and quick to implement in a script. However, if someone has an equally simple solution it will be welcome.

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a tweening engine like AniMate, you always animate the position of the object directly, ignoring any physics collisions that may occur. If you want an object to properly collide or work with joints, you have to use forces to move it an cannot change its position directly.

You can tween objects that affect the physics, but tweened objects are not affected by other physics objects. You should also make the rigidbody you're tweening kinematic.

The physics option in AniMate doesn't mean the object is affected by other objects through physics, it just changes how the tween is applied (in FixedUpdate instead of Update) to make sure the tweened object affects other physics objects properly.

In your example, the two tweens are started at the same time and the second tween overwrites the first one (which is why the object goes directly to the second point). You'll have to wait for the first tween to complete before starting the second one.

The easiest way to do that is using a Coroutine:

```
void FixedUpdate () {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
        StartCoroutine(TweenCoroutine());
    }
}

IEnumerator TweenCoroutine() {
    // To point 1
    Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
    props.Add("position", new Vector3(756f,112f,1124f));
    props.Add("physics", true);
    // Start first tween and wait for it to finish
    yield return Ani.Mate.To(transform, 2, props);  

    // To point 2
    Hashtable props2 = new Hashtable();
    props2.Add("position", new Vector3(731f,112f,1124f));
    props2.Add("physics", true);
    // Start second tween and wait for it to finish
    yield return Ani.Mate.To(transform, 2, props2);

    // etc...
}
```

AniMate doesn't support motion paths. [HOTween](http://www.holoville.com/hotween/) does and allows you to pass it a list of points the tweened object then passes through.

There's also a [new version](https://github.com/sttz/Animate/) of AniMate (now Animate) avaialable that has a fluid interface that's much nicer to use in C#.